# [Err] ORA-00054: ресурс занят и задано его получение с параметром NOWAIT, либо истекло время

Tags: oracle

Пытаюсь очистить таблицу (всего 1500 записей):

```
truncate TABLE EXPORT_LOG;
```

И получаю сообщение:

```
[SQL] truncate TABLE EXPORT_LOG
[Err] ORA-00054: ресурс занят и задано его получение с параметром NOWAIT, либо истекло время ожидания
```

А если сделать:

```
DELETE FROM EXPORT_LOG;
```

то можно ждать до бесконечности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блокировка стоит на таблицу. Посмотрите [тут](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=652758).